# iMac6,1 showing multicolor after installing mac os x 10.7

Tags: imac, startup, color, restart

It was on Os x 10.6.3 before I decided to install fresh OS x 10.7 everything was fine after the installation but when I restart the  it start showing multicolor as seen in the picture attached. I have shut it down couple of times still mo joy. Any help will be appreciated. [image]

Comment: That's a hardware issue - it could be the GPU or the screen itself.  What happens if you continue to boot?  Also, your upgrade won't have anything to do with it (the screen you're showing is the EFI boot screen and not macOS); it's just a coincidence the two happened together.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I didn’t want to believe it’s hardware issues cos i have an external windows bootable hard drive in it before restating it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying...

Comment: I need a way to fix the efi boot error maybe there might be luck rather than coupling the error just a suggestion. Because i recently checked the hard drive with disk Utility and everything seems okay.

Comment: What you're seeing is not an "error."  It's a failure.

Comment: Thank you allan and sorry for late response. I recently disassembled the imac and removed the graphics card try to heat it for some seconds and when I couple the imac and turn it on this time the screen was black and no chim sound when power on but the system and the fan was running well, pleae what could cause the sound not to up when powered on. Thanks